# Can I disable the Problem Window when using Go to Problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

When press <kbd>F8</kbd> (Go to next Problem), a window opens with an explanation of the problem. Can I disable this window or set something different?

[image: Window]

Can I instead of this window get the definition info? (assuming the problem is with the definition of something)
[image: Definition]

Comment: It is easy to modify `F8` to not open that problems overview.  Is that what you want to do?  And open the definitions hover instead?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from looking at the settings that exist in the current version at the time of thsi writing (v1.75) that contain the substring `problem` in the setting ID, there is not a setting to disable this problem explanation upon navigating back and forth between problems.

I also did not see any command/action to navigate back and forth between problems without opening the problem explanation.

It can be pretty easily closed by pressing <kbd>escape</kbd>.

If you really want such a feature, you can create a feature-request on [the VS Code GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).